# Discourse installation troubles

Tags: nginx, web-applications, forum, discourse

I tried to install Discourse on DigitalOcean following their tutorial:
https://github.com/discourse/discourse/blob/master/docs/INSTALL-cloud.md

Everything goes fine until one of the lasts points: Bootstrap Discourse.

I run the command `./launcher bootstrap app` it take around 5 minutes and then it gets freezed at this point (please see image):

http://postimg.org/image/gjzs7cvpn/

Can anybody help me please?
Thanks a lot

Comment: How long did you wait before declaring it frozen? That step (`bundle install`) is quite slow and is depending on both your internet connection speed and hardware.

Comment: Hello @ZogStriP , thanks for replying.
Its was like 5 minutes till that point... after that I waited around 15 minutes and it came the "broken pipe" error.

Do you know where the error may come from?
Thanks a lot

Comment: Could be because you're running this on a very low end VPS and it's freezing because it has not enough memory.

Comment: I am running discourse on a GCE with 1.7Gb of ram and even then it's struggling.  What are you using?

Answer (score 0):

As the document, you should run `./discourse-setup` . The configuration need about  2-8 minutes. Just wait.

Answer (score 0):

if you have discourse already installed and you are adding plugins or upgrading to new settings then run `./launcher rebuild app` but if installation is first time then remove docker and install new version again